# i have NSString value in addViewController and i want to display this value in UILabel of DetailsViewController

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uilabel

I am newbie to programming. Any help could be greatly appreciated.

It's in AddViewController.

```
NSLog(@"Am Currently at %@",locatedAt);

DetailsOfPeopleViewController *details=[DetailsOfPeopleViewController alloc];
   details.testAddressStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",locatedAt];
```

`details.testAddressStr` is displaying the value here, but it's not passing this value to DetailsViewController.

The value of `locatedAt` is displaying in the AddViewController. When I try to display this value in UILabel of DetailsViewController class it's not displaying that value in the label.

In DetailsViewController.h:

```
NSString *testAddressStr;

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *testAddressStr;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;
```

In DetailsViewController.m:

```
 [addressLabel setText:testAddressStr];
```

Am also trying it this way:

```
addressLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",testAddressStr];
```

I'm not really getting where I'm making a mistake...

Comment: where are you calling the [addressLabel setText:testAddressStr];

Comment: am calling [addressLabel setText:testAddressStr]; this in viewDidLoad of the DeatilViewController. Thank you for the quick reply..

Comment: hey suvarna +1 bhi karo na yaar..:)

Comment: Hey actually am not sure how to +1..i accepted u r ans by cliking on the empty sign mark then it became green sign mark ...this is the way to make +1 r8??

Comment: Just click on upper arrow nearBy my answer...  like :-   ^   its the sign of upvoating

Comment: upper side of green icon there in 3 thing..one is down arrow second is my point and third is up arrow... up arrow for up voting..  and down arrow for down voting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data using [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**SetValue**

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtView.text]; forKey:@"testPersonNotesStr"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

**GetValue**

```
testPersonNotesStr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"testPersonNotesStr"];
NSLog(@"PERSON NOTE is........ %@",testPersonNotesStr);
```

**:)**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to you are assigning an autoreleased variable. It's released before you display it on the detailView. So you need to retain it. Or You need to allocate the `testAddressStr`.

**Just replace this line:**

```
details.testAddressStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",locatedAt];
```

**with:**

```
details.testAddressStr = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",locatedAt] retain];
```

**or**

```
details.testAddressStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",locatedAt]];
```

Comment: Actually what i want is , i need to display the value of NSString(its displaying in its own view) in other view on UILabel...

Comment: NSLog(@" addressLabel.text ISSS... %@",addressLabel.text);
    NSLog(@"testAddressStr iss %@",testAddressStr);       if i print like this its displaying as (null)...

Comment: @suvarna: are you allocating the  testAddressStr anywhere else ?

Comment: Hey!!! i solved this issue...made some other customization to my app ...Thanks to all for the clues...

Answer (score 0):

retain your string **`locatedAt`**, where you have initialized it.
like this

```
[locatedAt retain];
```

Enjoy Programming

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as the "scope of an object" in Objective-C. Scope rules have nothing to do with an object's lifetime — the retain count is everything.

You usually need to claim ownership of your instance variables. See the Objective-C memory management rules. With a retain property, your property setter claims ownership of the new value and relinquishes ownership of the old one. With an assign property, the surrounding code has to do this, which is just as mess in terms of responsibilities and separation of concerns. The reason you would use an assign property is in a case where you can't retain the value (such as non-object types like BOOL or NSRect) or when retaining it would cause unwanted side effects.

Incidentally, in the case of an NSString, the correct kind of property is usually copy. That way it can't change out from under you if somebody passes in an NSMutableString (which is valid — it is a kind of NSString).

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
 [addressLabel setText:testAddressStr];
```

with the following

```
 [addressLabel setText:self.testAddressStr];
```