# How do I save values from a UITextField in the FlipsideViewController and use them in the MainViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

**SEE EDIT AT BOTTOM**

I am making a `UtilityView` application for the iPhone and I want to be able to change values from the `FlipsideViewController`.  I have a problem that whenever I switch back to the MainView from the FlipsideView, the values of the text fields that I had changed in the FlipsideView are seemingly reset to 0.  In the `MainViewController.m`, under the `flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:`

```
playToInt = [controller.playTo.text intValue];

computerMoveSpeed = [controller.aiSpeed.text intValue];
```

The text field 'playTo' coordinates with the integer 'playToInt' and the text field 'aiSpeed' coordinates with the integer 'computerMoveSpeed'.  I think this should save the values, even when the ViewDidLoad runs again, but they both seem to be reset to 0.

```
if (playToInt != 10 || computerMoveSpeed != 3)   
{
  playBool = true;
} 
else 
{
  playBool = false;
}
```

I know that the boolean is working because I can change the integers' values with it, but they always default back to 0.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I have consulted the previous question 'Passing UISegmentedControl values from FlipSideViewController in an Utility application to the mainviewcontroller…' and that does not work for me... I am have too many possible values to use an index or a switch.

EDIT: I am trying something that I think is really close to working... I feel like it just has bad syntax or something... I have in the MainViewController.m:

```
computerMoveSpeed = [FlipsideViewController.aiSpeed.text intValue];

playToInt = [FlipsideViewController.playTo.text];
```

EDIT: I have something that is similar to the last one but I think it will have a better chance of working with some help...

in the `FlipsideViewController.m` I have

> _playToNumber = [_playTo.text intValue];

and in the `MainViewController.m`

> playToInt = [controller.playToNumber];

Any help is greatly appreciated, but as some additional info, on the string in the `MainViewController` it says it needs an identifier on the `playToNumber` variable, but it is declared as `int`... I don't know if there is an identifier for `int`s but if there is, please let me know!

EDIT: Is there any way to save the values in a usable format for the `MainViewController` using the `prepareForSegue` function in the `FlipsideViewController`?

EDIT: I figured out that it was just getting the initial values when it loaded the `ViewDidLoad`, so I started using a timer to retrieve the values.  This seems to be working, I just need to know how to access these values from the `MainViewController`?

Comment: use NSUserDefault follow my ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509999/i-have-nsstring-value-in-addviewcontroller-and-i-want-to-display-this-value-in-u/13619879#13619879

Comment: I don't need to set the defaults, I already did that... I need to be able to save the values that I change in the flipside and use them in the mainView

Comment: are you using pushViewControlller

Comment: when view did load called then the all the view again allocating thats why ...

Comment: you want value of playToInt as  [controller.playTo.text intValue];..not 0, m i right

Comment: yes, I want playToInt and computerMoveSpeed to != 0 unless specified in the flipside; i am not using pushViewController

Comment: make object of an string like @property(non,ret)nsstring *string;

Comment: then paas your value to this string ..and in viewWillAppear put this string value in where you want

Comment: When I try to pass the value to the NSInteger using 'NSInteger *number = [FlipsideViewController._playTo.text IntegerValue];' it tells me that "property '_playTo' is not found on any type of Flipside View Controller"... is there a better way to do this?
@Rajneesh071

Comment: first off all its 'NSInteger number=...'

Comment: and in FlipsideViewController, make property of _playTo, like @property(retain,.)..and synthesize it then use

Comment: hey dont get value from previous view, just send value from previous view, mean when you are getting your view from FlipsideViewController, then send value to number,  @property(nonatomic)NSInteger *number;

Comment: could you clarify a little?
@Rajneesh071

Comment: I just discovered that the flipsideViewController isn't even changing the values within itself... i used nslog and it gave me the default, 10, but it wouldn't change when i typed in it

Comment: never mind... i just realized that the viewdidload only runs once so i put a timer and it works now

Comment: I have in the `FlipsideViewController.m` :
    `_playToNumber = [_playTo.text intValue];`
and in the `MainViewController.m`
    `playToInt = [controller.playToNumber];`
I think I am really close, but it says 'expected identifier' on the second string of code

Comment: no... it is not solved, but I feel like i am close... @Rajneesh071

Comment: I have a class that is connected to a timer when the `FlipsideViewController` is called and this has the values being updated, even when the `FlipsideViewController` is dismissed.... Is there a way to access this from the `MainViewController.m`?

Comment: can I use the 

    - (void)run
    {
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate to send values back to `MainViewController`. See [this tutorial](http://alexefish.com/post/15966868557/understanding-and-creating-delegates-in-objective-c) to learn how to use delegates.

Answer (score 0):

You have many way to do this task,

**1.** [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Follow ma answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509999/i-have-nsstring-value-in-addviewcontroller-and-i-want-to-display-this-value-in-u/13619879#13619879)

**2.** Using `Getters, setters, property`

Follow ma answer  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602840/passing-the-value-from-one-class-to-other-class/13606108#13606108)

**EDIT**

If you want `int` or `NSInteger` then no need for retain
just do

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger YourIntValue;
```

and

```
_playToNumber = [_playTo.text intValue];

MainViewController *MVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
MVC.playToInt=_playToNumber;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:MVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: followed instructions, but I need it to be an `int` or `NSInteger` value, not a `NSString` and when I tried, it told me that the `copy` attribute had to be of object type...

Comment: it runs without errors, but how do i get it to be the same value as my `flipside` value?

Comment: how are you moving from the class flipside

Comment: sorry for the long reply... I had no internet for a week, but I am using the default info button and done button (in the navigation bar) that are installed on the `view` by default.

Comment: when you are moving to your new view then paas value that time...and use in new view..

Comment: MainViewController *MVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
MVC.playToInt=_playToNumber; then push to new view

Comment: how do you push it to the main view? does it do it automatically?